# Wrong question used for Audit in Reopen queue?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, unclear

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/10177580) and I wonder why. The question got closed as "Unclear what you are asking". I think I understand the question, even though I'm not familiar with Objective-C. Four people tried to answer. Two of the answers look like potential solutions to the asker's issue, one is on a tangent, the fourth a failed attempt.

Personally, since I'm no Objective-C coder, I wouldn't do the edit to the question. But I did vote to reopen, even though that was the original reason why I failed the audit.

My point rather is: Why did it even make it into the audit queue? Is this a hidden attempt to do real, more thorough reviews in the audits? ;-) Seriously, it is annoying how often I get audits where the state of the post is rather dubious. Could we tune the audit algorithm to present us with clearer questions?